# exception during geoip databases updateorg.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-8.6.2 and I am getting below error when I'm trying to start the elasticsearch.bat file.

Error:

[2023-03-09T14:49:54,780][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [DESKTOP-8N84PF5] exception during geoip databases updateorg.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active
at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.6.2/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:134)
at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.6.2/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:274)
at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.6.2/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:102)
at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.6.2/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.elasticsearch.server@8.6.2/org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42)

Trying to start eleasticsearch

Answer (score 2):

This error is not mean your Elasticsearch is not working.

Check your elasticsearch status:

```
curl -k -u elastic:<your_password> "https://localhost:9200/_cat/health"
```

If you want you can disable `geoip.downloader` to get rid of this error.

```
curl -ks -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "persistent": { 
  "ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled" : "false"
  }
}'
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geoip-processor.html